# In a given series, counting the number of times a value appear before and after, a given number

Tags: vba, excel

Editing Question that it May be helpful to others in future.

In a given series of Numbers, Values appearing before and after a given number is to be allocated to their respective Tables as can be seen in the Images attached.

The Number Series is as follows. I.e. 5 Being the first number to be inputted, and 3 Being the last. Hence 4 Is Before 2 and 3 Is after 2.

> Series
>       3
>       2
>       4
>       8
>       0
>       8
>       7
>       3
>       8
>       7
>       0
>       0
>       4
>       9
>       6
>       3
>       9
>       7
>       4
>       5

A Gist of Code that was being used:

```
'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim cell As Variant

  myrange = Range("B1:B30").Value

  For each cell in myRange

  if (cell=range("H2")) then

  'save the value of current cell if it matches 

   range("h3")=cell.offset(1,0)

  if (cell.offset(1,0) = range("h3"))

     'Count offset value (Value in cell.offset(1,0)) each time it appears before current cell (cell as in cell in my range)
 endif

     end if
    next cell
     end sub
```

The example is a shortened version of what was being done. A more efficient method is welcomed.

[image: Excel [Snippet link][1]]

Thanks in advance. :)

Edit: added Expected [Output Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6tXU.png)

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are asking.  could you show what your expected output would be?

Comment: "Before & After"? or "Before or After?" i.e. row 6 = 0 AND row before & after = 8. Then does the range 'wrap'? meaning row 2 has no prior row unless you go to the last row in the range (same concept applies to last row).

Comment: @ScottCraner Added expected output snippet for before numbers. The same method would be applied to after.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn It's before and after. Yes, Before 8 would be 0 and after 4. Though if the output can be plotted on 2 separate tables to make it easier to read, that should work as well. No it does not Wrap. The Values are being assigned from another sheet which has the series inputted and each time a number is entered a row is inserted above it (Hence the Sr.No is reversed).

Comment: Now I'm confused. You say "Before 8 would be 0 and after 4". If working from top to bottom I see the first 8 has a 4 BEFORE and a 0 AFTER. But then you mention the Sr being reversed, so I thought yow were going bottom to top. But then I see your example and it appears top to bottom. Please clarify.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Yes, it should go bottom to top. Though since i'm new to vba in excel, I have come to learn it's tougher to go bottom to top. So was going top to bottom but keeping true to the order. As I mentioned values are being entered in b2 on another sheet, and each time a value is entered a new row is inserted above it for the next value. Hence first 0 was inputted then 8 and then 4, which makes 0=Before,8 and 4=after. Hope that helps. Thanks for trying to understand the Question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()
Dim arr, r, b, a

    arr = Range("A1:A20").Value
    Range("D4").Resize(10, 10).ClearContents
    Range("D17").Resize(10, 10).ClearContents

    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) - 1
        b = arr(r, 1)
        a = arr(r + 1, 1)

        With Range("D4")
            .Offset(b, a).Value = .Offset(b, a).Value + 1
        End With

        With Range("D17")
            .Offset(a, b).Value = .Offset(a, b).Value + 1
        End With

    Next r

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Wow! I Really think that's what I'm looking for, Just looking at the Output. Though I do not understand the code. Hence I'll try and apply it to the sheet and understand the working, and come back with the info. Thank you once again. :)

Answer (score 0):

Now that I know 'before & after' are defined the opposite of what I assumed, I changed the code to generate the correct results.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim lLastRow    As Long
Dim lRow        As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BefAfter")
    ws.Activate

    ' Get last row number
    lLastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    ' Clear BEFORE counts
    Range("H3:Q12").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    ' Clear AFTER counts
    Range("H18:Q27").Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    For lRow = 2 To lLastRow
        ' Get all the after #'s
        If lRow > 2 Then
            ws.Cells(18 + ws.Cells(lRow, 2), 8 + ws.Cells(lRow - 1, 2)) = ws.Cells(18 + ws.Cells(lRow, 2), 8 + ws.Cells(lRow - 1, 2)) + 1
        End If

        ' Get all the before #'s
        If lRow < lLastRow Then
            ws.Cells(3 + ws.Cells(lRow, 2), 8 + ws.Cells(lRow + 1, 2)) = ws.Cells(3 + ws.Cells(lRow, 2), 8 + ws.Cells(lRow + 1, 2)) + 1
        End If
    Next lRow

    'MsgBox "Finished"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've run the code on a new sheet I've named as 'BefAfter' but found a 122 125 and #'s which I can't seem to make sense off. Am I doing something wrong? I ran it without changing anything. [img]http://i.imgur.com/kZRGnsm.png?1[/img] Changed Set myrange = ws.Range("B2:B174" & lLastRow) and same result. can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: Not sure why you got that 122 / 125 result. Now that I know the real order of 'last to first', I modified my code. One possible issue you may have encountered would be if there are rows with anything present following your 'data range'. In my testing, if I shorten the rows to less than 27 (the last row where I place counts) it can cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it though it still is coming up with an unknown value of 16. Will try to figure out why. Thanks once again. :)